# Speeding up sumproduct calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file that contains data from GIS that has just under 215k rows of data.

Of this data there are 3 columns that are of interest to me:

- GRID_ID (roughly 18k unique values)
- Croptype (15 unique values)
- AREA (all unique values)

Now I know I can get a summation table of this (the area for each combination of Grid_ID and Croptype) by using this formula in Cell C2. Whilst column A contains the unique GRID_ID's, in ascending order, and row 1 contains the Croptype's starting in column C.

`=Sumproduct((GRID_ID=$A2)*(Croptype=C$1)*AREA)`

Where in the formula the column names are replaced with the actual ranges of the data.

Now this works fine for a smaller dataset, but for my set it is problematically slow. Would there be a more efficient way of going about calculating this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS()

```
=SUMIFS(AREA,GRID_ID,$A2,Croptype,C$1)
```

Which should be quicker.  But even too many of these will slow down the calcs.  you may want vba to do the whole at once using variant arrays.

Comment: Does this give me the sum of area for the combination of croptype and gridid?

Comment: @Luuklag you stated that all the values are unique, so there would be no summing, only returning the one value,  The intersection of grid_id and croptype in area.

Comment: The values of area are by itself unique, but there could be multiple occurences of the same combination of croptype and grid_id. I need to sum the area of those instances.

Comment: @Luuklag i miss read,  try the sumifs.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner, would 253K Sumifs be considered too many? I'm afraid it is?

Comment: as the source of data, no.  As that many of the formula, yes.  You will want vba to load the whole at once.

Comment: I ended up using this sumifs and running it on a secondary computer. Wasnt worth the effort writing a macro for what turned out to be only 3 files.